# Modifying the orbeon-resources-private.jar files causes white screen

Tags: orbeon, xbl

I am trying to create my own custom components in orbeon.

I have been following the steps from the documentation and it said to unzip the jar file 'orbeon-resources-private' I did that and done what I needed to do inside the folder. I then zip it back up into a jar file and copy back over to orbeon.

When I start orbeon back up all i get is a white screen. I check the console and see I am getting a GET 404 not found. What the hell.

Next I put the original jar back and it worked again. So now I unzipped the jar and just zipped it back up again. (Surely that will work). Nothing, still a white screen.

Why cant I put another jar bar the original to get it working.

(I have tried creating jar from command line, zipping it and changing file extension, just adding .jar to a folder, all dont work.)

Could really use some insight to this...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which documenation page are you referring to?

I don't know why you would want to modify the orbeon-resources-private.jar.

You can put your own components into WEB-INF/resources or you can configure another path as documented in [Overriding or adding resources without changing Orbeon Forms](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/overriding-adding-resources).

Comment: the plan was to remove the components us-state and number and ad in my own ones for the uk. How can I remove them without modifying orbeon-resources-private.jar?

Comment: Resources are loaded in order of priority. Check the How it works section of [Overriding or adding resources without changing Orbeon Forms](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/overriding-adding-resources). Resources in the directory that you configure will override the ones in the jars. Just put the files you changed in that directory. I think WEB-INF/resources will override the jars as well. If you're modifying any of the properties though, you should just override the specific properties in your own config/properties-local.xml file rather than copying the property file.

Comment: thanks, I put my changes into WEB-INF/resources/xbl/orbeon and it now works. Thank you sir :)